# Using iTerm2 to moodify and massage commands before executing

Tags: unix, terminal, iterm2, productivity-power-tools

I'm looking for a way to work with a long command on a Terminal such as iTerm2.

In the perfect world, I'd have a text box that I can modify then hitting Command+Enter will send it to "execute" - but the editing experience would be more like VSCode than terminals which make it a pain to jump around.

Example

curl 'xxx' 
-X 'OPTIONS' 
-H 'authority: xxx 
-H 'accept: */*' 
-H 'access-control-request-method: POST' 
-H 'access-control-request-headers: content-type' 
-H 'origin: xxx' 
-H 'user-agent: xxx' 
-H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' 
-H 'sec-fetch-site: same-site' 
-H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' 
-H 'referer: xxx' 
-H 'accept-language: xxx' 
-b 'sessionID'='xxx' \
--compressed

UPDATE:

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S0RQdu5yV4) which kind of works but it doesn't show the output.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3 of iTerm you can use [Composer](https://iterm2.com/version3.html#Composer) feature.

Use

- `Cmd` + `shift` + `.` = to open the editor window
- `Shift` + `enter`  = to send the command for execution